# HTML form press 'Enter' in an input text cause click on button

Tags: html, forms, events, button, input

http://jsfiddle.net/PCGvG/

Why in this example when I press 'Enter' in the input text, it executes the `onclick`? While using `<input type="button">` doesn't...

Comment: This is more of browser behaviour, rather than angularjs

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The element `<button>` has `type="submit"` by default. See http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.5

Solution: if you don't want the click handler of the button to be called, give it type="button" explicitly.

```html
<form name="myForm">
    <button type="button" id="test">Click</button>
    <input type="text" name="q" />
</form>
```

(Pressing Enter will still submit the form though, at least on some browsers.)

With regards to your comment that `<input type="button">` acts differently: that's right. An input with type="button" acts the same way as a button with type="button", while an input with type="submit" would act the same as a button with type="submit".